# AttributeError when using python deepcopy

Tags: python, deep-copy, cyclic-reference

I have a class that has `__eq__` and `__hash__` overridden, to make its objects act as dictionary keys. Each object also carries a dictionary, keyed by other objects of the same class. I get a weird `AttributeError` when I try to `deepcopy` the whole structure. I am using Python 3.6.0 on OsX.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) it looks as if `deepcopy` uses a `memo` dictionary to cache the objects it has already copied, so nested structures should not be a problem. What am I doing wrong then? Should I code up my own `__deepcopy__` method to work around this? How?

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Node:

    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.id = p_id
        self.edge_dict = {}
        self.degree = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def add_edge(self, p_node, p_data):
        if p_node not in self.edge_dict:
            self.edge_dict[p_node] = p_data
            self.degree += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node1 = Node(1)
    node2 = Node(2)
    node1.add_edge(node2, "1->2")
    node2.add_edge(node1, "2->1")
    node1_copy = deepcopy(node1)
```

---

```
File ".../node_test.py", line 15, in __hash__
    return hash(self.id)
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Side-note: Did you meant to make an edge from `node1` to `node1`? I suspect you didn't. Doesn't fix the problem (cyclic dependencies are cyclic), but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: you are right, fixed. still getting the error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cyclic dependencies are a problem for `deepcopy` when you:

1. Have classes that must be hashed and contain reference cycles, and
2. Don't ensure hash-related (and equality related) invariants are established at object *construction*, not just *initialization*

The problem is unpickling an object (`deepcopy`, by default, copies custom objects by pickling and unpickling, unless a special `__deepcopy__` method is defined) creates the empty object without initializing it, then tries to fill in its attributes one by one. When it tries to fill in `node1`'s attributes, it needs to initialize `node2`, which in turn relies on the partially created `node1` (in both cases due to the `edge_dict`). At the time it's trying to fill in the `edge_dict` for one `Node`, the `Node` it's adding to `edge_dict` doesn't have its `id` attribute set yet, so the attempt to hash it fails.

You can correct this by using `__new__` to ensure invariants are established prior to initializing mutable, possibly recursive attributes, and defining the `pickle` helper `__getnewargs__` (or `__getnewargs_ex__`) to make it use them properly. Specifically, change you class definition to:

```
class Node:
    # __new__ instead of __init__ to establish necessary id invariant
    # You could use both __new__ and __init__, but that's usually more complicated
    # than you really need
    def __new__(cls, p_id):
        self = super().__new__(cls)  # Must explicitly create the new object
        # Aside from explicit construction and return, rest of __new__
        # is same as __init__
        self.id = p_id
        self.edge_dict = {}
        self.degree = 0
        return self  # __new__ returns the new object

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        # Return the arguments that *must* be passed to __new__
        return (self.id,)

    # ... rest of class is unchanged ...
```

Note: If this is Python 2 code, make sure to explicitly inherit from `object` and change `super()` to `super(Node, cls)` in `__new__`; the code given is the simpler Python 3 code.

An alternate solution that handles *only* `copy.deepcopy`, without supporting pickling or requiring the use of `__new__`/`__getnewargs__` (which require new-style classes) would be to override deepcopying only. You'd define the following extra method on your original class (and make sure the module imports `copy`), and otherwise leave it untouched:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    # Deepcopy only the id attribute, then construct the new instance and map
    # the id() of the existing copy to the new instance in the memo dictionary
    memo[id(self)] = newself = self.__class__(copy.deepcopy(self.id, memo))
    # Now that memo is populated with a hashable instance, copy the other attributes:
    newself.degree = copy.deepcopy(self.degree, memo)
    # Safe to deepcopy edge_dict now, because backreferences to self will
    # be remapped to newself automatically
    newself.edge_dict = copy.deepcopy(self.edge_dict, memo)
    return newself
```

Comment: Note: [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) and [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) only apply to new-style classes, which is why I mention explicitly inheriting from `object` on Python 2 (where the default is old-style classes; on Py3, only new-style classes exist, so it's not an issue). It also requires the use of pickle protocol 2 or higher, but thankfully, `copy.deepcopy` explicitly uses the highest possible protocol when pickling, so that's never a problem on any Python with new-style classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful.

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich: You're welcome. For the record, there are other ways to fix this, all of which involve messing with pickle or copy-related special methods, so if using `__new__` is a problem, let me know. Using `__new__` and `__getnewargs__` happens to be fairly straightforward (and covers both pickling and deepcopying), but options exist if you must avoid `__new__`/`__getnewargs__`.