# Create a set of class objects which contain that very set as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, typeerror, attributeerror

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = set()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y, self.z))

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if not isinstance(other, Something):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

The above is the class definition. Inside main:

```
blah = []

for i in range(5):
    blah.append(Something(i,i+1))

blah[0].z.add(blah[1])
```

For this, I get the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` error. One solution I found here was to make z a `frozenset()` but that gives `AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'add'`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should omit `self.z` from your hash implementation.

Comment: Given that your class is mutable, maybe it *shouldn't* be hashable.

Comment: If the `__eq__` method cares only about the values of `self.x` and `self.y`, there is no good reason why the `__hash__` method should include `self.z` in its hash calculations. The two methods are meant to be kept compatible.

Comment: @khelwood it gives me `AttributeError: 'Something' object has no attribute 'x'` on doing so.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania That is some kind of separate problem not reproducible from the code you have posted.

Comment: Various comments have been made suggesting that the `__eq__` and `__hash__` should necessarily march in lockstep. But it's not difficult to think of reasonable use cases where two instances have **equality** while still retaining distinct **identity**. Poker hands, mathematical expressions, etc. As usual, *it depends*.

Comment: @FMc Hashes have nothing to do with identity; they are used to distribute objects among the slots of certain containers, nothing more. The only requirement is that `x == y` implies `hash(x) == hash(y)`; there are no restrictions on the hash values if `x != y`.

Comment: @chepner You're talking narrowly about hash implementations. But set membership (the question at hand) is very much tied to the concept of identity – at least in many use cases. Again, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm talking about the documented use of `__hash__` in Python.

Comment: @khelwood https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283738/attributeerror-when-using-python-deepcopy - this is the real problem.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania That might well be a problem you are having. It's not the problem this question was asking about.

Comment: @khelwood thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should omit `self.z` from your `__hash__` method.

Since your `__eq__` method ignores `self.z`, it would be incorrect for `__hash__` to take account of it anyway. And it solves the issue of `self.z` being an unhashable (and mutable) type.